# Nine pronouns... how to distinguish them all?

Tags: word-choice

So there are nine related pronouns...

kore kono koko
sore sono soko
are ano ako

The first kana tells you where object is, and the second kana tells you whether it is a thing (re and no) or a place (ko).

My question is... what’s the difference between “re” and “no”? How do you decided between “kore” and “kono”?

Comment: kore is a noun, kono is an adjective